# cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Tags: oracle

Hello everyone am trying to insert data into base tables via a view that joins more than two tables. I have an instead of trigger that should insert the data into the tables, not sure where have gone wrong on the code. The following is the codes have used.

**View**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "NEW_APPLICANT" ("FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME", "ADDRESS",
     "MATH_SCORE", "ENGLISH_SCORE", "SCIENCE_SCORE") AS 
select APPLICANT.FIRST_NAME as FIRST_NAME,
       APPLICANT.LAST_NAME as LAST_NAME,
       APPLICANT.ADDRESS as ADDRESS,
       RESULT.MATH_SCORE as MATH_SCORE,
       RESULT.ENGLISH_SCORE as ENGLISH_SCORE,
       RESULT.SCIENCE_SCORE as SCIENCE_SCORE 
from   RESULT RESULT, APPLICANT APPLICANT 
where  APPLICANT.APPLICANT_ID=RESULT.APPLICANT_ID
/
```

**Trigger**

```
create or replace TRIGGER application_new_insert
   INSTEAD OF INSERT ON NEW_APPLICANT
   DECLARE
     duplicate_info EXCEPTION;
     PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (duplicate_info, -00001);
   BEGIN
     INSERT INTO APPLICANT
       (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ADDRESS)
     VALUES (
     :new.FIRST_NAME,
     :new.LAST_NAME,
     :new.ADDRESS);
   INSERT INTO RESULT ( MATH_SCORE, ENGLISH_SCORE, SCIENCE_SCORE)
   VALUES (
     :new.MATH_SCORE,
     :new.ENGLISH_SCORE,
     :new.SCIENCE_SCORE);
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN duplicate_info THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (
         num=> -20107,
         msg=> 'Duplicate customer or order ID');
   END application_new_insert;
```

Table definitions. Table **`applicant`**:

```
CREATE TABLE "APPLICANT" 
( "APPLICANT_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  "ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(35), 
  CONSTRAINT "PK_APPLICANT_ID" 
    PRIMARY KEY ("APPLICANT_ID") ENABLE 
) / 

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TR_APPLICANT" 
before insert on APPLICANT 
for each row 
begin 
  if :NEW.APPLICANT_ID is null then 
    select APPLICANT_ID_SEQ.nextval 
    into :NEW.APPLICANT_ID 
    from dual; 
  end if; 
end; / 

ALTER TRIGGER "TR_APPLICANT" 
  ENABLE /
```

Table **`result`**:

```
CREATE TABLE "RESULT" 
( "RESULT_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"APPLICANT_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"MATH_SCORE" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"ENGLISH_SCORE" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"SCIENCE_SCORE" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
CONSTRAINT "PK_RESULT_ID" PRIMARY KEY ("RESULT_ID") ENABLE 
) / 

ALTER TABLE "RESULT" 
  ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_RESULT_APPLICANT_ID" 
    FOREIGN KEY ("APPLICANT_ID") 
    REFERENCES "APPLICANT" ("APPLICANT_ID") 
  ENABLE / 

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TR_RESULT" 
before insert on RESULT 
for each row 
begin 
  if :NEW.RESULT_ID is null then 
    select RESULT_ID_SEQ.nextval 
    into :NEW.RESULT_ID 
    from dual; 
  end if; 
end; / 

ALTER TRIGGER "TR_RESULT"
  ENABLE /
```

Comment: What error did you get? What is the problem?

Comment: am getting the ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table error

Answer (score 1):

In your view you do not fetch all the key fields from both tables. Oracle needs that to be able to do the update. In your case you do an insert so I suppose that you do not provide the primary keys for both tables. Since you did not gave the structure of both tables I cannot be more specific.

Comment: ok let me provide the structure of the tables, i have sequences defined for primary key generation and triggers that insert the numbers generated.

Comment: CREATE TABLE  "APPLICANT" 
   ( "APPLICANT_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "ADDRESS" VARCHAR2(35), 
  CONSTRAINT "PK_APPLICANT_ID" PRIMARY KEY ("APPLICANT_ID") ENABLE
   )
/


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "TR_APPLICANT" 
  before insert on APPLICANT               
  for each row  
begin   
  if :NEW.APPLICANT_ID is null then 
    select APPLICANT_ID_SEQ.nextval into :NEW.APPLICANT_ID from dual; 
  end if; 
end; 

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "TR_APPLICANT" ENABLE
/

Comment: @chibwe edit your question, don't post code in comments.

Comment: CREATE TABLE  "RESULT" 
   ( "RESULT_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "APPLICANT_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "MATH_SCORE" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "ENGLISH_SCORE" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "SCIENCE_SCORE" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  CONSTRAINT "PK_RESULT_ID" PRIMARY KEY ("RESULT_ID") ENABLE
   )
/
ALTER TABLE  "RESULT" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_RESULT_APPLICANT_ID" FOREIGN KEY ("APPLICANT_ID")
   REFERENCES  "APPLICANT" ("APPLICANT_ID") ENABLE
/

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "TR_RESULT" 
  before insert on RESULT               
  for each row  
begin   
  if :NEW.RESULT_ID is null then 
    select RESULT_ID_SEQ.nextval into :NEW.RESULT_ID from dual; 
  end if; 
end; 

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "TR_RESULT" ENABLE
/

Comment: It will only insert one row in each. The problem here is that the view is created without any primary key field included. So updates are not possible. The error message must be based upon this.

Comment: @ypercube thanks, am new to stackexchange also new developer. trying to learn code!

Comment: @marco i have my primary keys generated by a sequence and inserted by a trigger, should i also include the primary key fields in the view as they are automatically inserted

Comment: That is what the error says `non key-preserved table`. The view has no 'knowledge' of the keys in case of an update. I suppose that this triggers the error even if you insert.

Comment: So looking at the current code structure, how can i best resolve this issue?

Comment: Add the primary keys of both tables to the returned fields of the view. make sure that in your insert that you provide the primary key fields too. Especially the `APPLICANT_ID` for the `RESULT` table.